# Spark parquet number of files using repartition without partitionBy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

In preparation for a certification I was refreshing and noticed this for a small dataset looking at dataframe writer functionality.

A trivial example of a roundrobin partitioning with incidentally only 1 partition filled after repartition - in this simple case:

```
val y = (1 to 5).toList
val yDF = y.toDF("number")
val yDF2 = yDF.repartition(8)      // Goes from 5 to 8 partitions, round-robin, only 1 partition filled
yDF2.rdd.partitions.size           // 8 partitions, only 1 filled
yDF2.rdd.glom().collect()          // res141: Array[Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = Array(Array(), Array(), Array(), Array(), Array(), Array(), Array([1], [2], [3], [4], [5]), Array())

yDF2.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("some_parts_data.parquet")
```

This yields 2 files written. But only 1 partition contains all the data in this case. Why is this so so?

If I have 12 values over 8 partitions, it writes 8 partitions / files, as an aside.

parquet of course. Curious.

Comment: can you post sample data ??

Comment: @Srinivas   simpler example